# Repository/controller: How can I force TYPO3 to load the field "sorting"?

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-6.1.x

In a controller/template I'd like to have access to the field `sorting` of an entity.

I've tried to access it like:

```
$category->getSorting();
```

But it fails, as the method does not exist. When I dump the entity, all those meta fields, like `hidden`, `starttime` etc. aren't listed at all.

How can I tell TYPO3 to load those fields along with the other fields of the entitiy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are in Extbase context, you have to add the property to your model or (if you use the model of another extension) extend it and add the property. In both cases a getter and a setter method is needed if you want to access and edit the properties value:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 */
protected $sorting;

public function setSorting($sorting) {
    $this->sorting = $sorting;
}

public function getSorting() {
    return $this->sorting;
}
```

Make sure you have that field configured in the TCA as well:

```
...
'columns' => array(
    'sorting' => array(
        'label' => 'sorting',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'passthrough'
        )
    ),
    ...
```

After this you should be able to access the sorting property.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I also had to add it to the list `searchFields` in `ext_tables.php` as well.

Comment: waaat? You want your users search to return matches in the sorting field?

Comment: in 6.2 (have not tried other) I also had to add the sorting field to `showRecordFieldList` to make this work